# How to detect Visual Studio edition programmatically?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to detect programmatically the version of installed Visual Studio.
I already tried [this](https://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx) and [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/detecting-system-requirements?view=vs-2017) but I can't find the key `vs` in registry. I tried on Visual Studio Community 2017.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the safest way is using WMI, quick and simple, returns all info needed.

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(); 
            searcher.Query = new SelectQuery("MSFT_VSInstance ", "", new[] { "Caption", "Version", "ProductLocation" });
            ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
            ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator em = collection.GetEnumerator();

            while (em.MoveNext())
            {
                ManagementBaseObject baseObj = em.Current;
                if (baseObj.Properties["Version"].Value != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(baseObj.Properties["Caption"].Value.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine(baseObj.Properties["Version"].Value.ToString());
                    Debug.WriteLine(baseObj.Properties["ProductLocation"].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Chose all the properties of interest, execute "Get-CimInstance MSFT_VSInstance" in the powershell and you see all info available.

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/tools-for-managing-visual-studio-instances?view=vs-2019

If you need to do this programmatically good luck!  The API's are not stable between releases.  I did a C# solution for detecting VS2017 and incrementing the version from 15.0 to 16.0 gives the error 1054.

The above link shows you multiple different ways of finding the versions out there and I recommend attempting to use that for your program or installation instead of coming up with a homegrown solution because when it comes to API compatibility MS kind of throws devs to the wolves with it's most discrete not used very much API's At least in my experience when it comes to Visual studio API's between major version of visual studio.

To be more elaborate, if you wish to detect Vs2017 and VS2019 you need to detect the existence of VSWhere.exe which will come standard from the Visual Studio installer.
I believe this location doesn't change: %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\Vswhere.exe

you can find all the information you need about vswhere via this link:
https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere
If you're using an installer this is probably the best current way to find out the location of Installs of Visual Studio.

If you absolutely need a programmatic way of finding the installer this is a COM implementation that I used in the past for find VS2017 but this fails to find VS2019 for some reason for me.  When I increment the version to 16 it fails for me.  I can offer you this much in code sample but I can't spend time helping you to get this to work.

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupInstance, __uuidof(ISetupInstance));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupInstance2, __uuidof(ISetupInstance2));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IEnumSetupInstances, __uuidof(IEnumSetupInstances));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupConfiguration, __uuidof(ISetupConfiguration));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupConfiguration2, __uuidof(ISetupConfiguration2));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupHelper, __uuidof(ISetupHelper));
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(ISetupPackageReference, __uuidof(ISetupPackageReference));

module_ptr GetQuery(_Outptr_result_maybenull_ ISetupConfiguration** ppQuery);

UINT __stdcall GetVS2017Path(MSIHANDLE hModule)
{
    TraceOut(hModule, _T("In GetVS2017Path"), 1);

    try
    {
        int version = 15;

        const wstring VCCompilerType(L"Component");
        const wstring VCCompilerID(L"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64");

        CoInitializer init;

        ISetupConfigurationPtr query;
        auto lib = GetQuery(&query);

        ISetupConfiguration2Ptr query2(query);
        IEnumSetupInstancesPtr e;

        checkResult(query2->EnumAllInstances(&e));

        ISetupHelperPtr helper(query);

        ISetupInstance* pInstances[1] = { nullptr };
        auto hr = e->Next(1, pInstances, nullptr);
        while (S_OK == hr)
        {
            // Wrap instance without AddRef'ing.
            ISetupInstancePtr instance(pInstances[0], false);
            bstr_t bstrVersion;
            checkResult(instance->GetInstallationVersion(bstrVersion.GetAddress()));
            ULONGLONG ullVersion;
            checkResult(helper->ParseVersion(bstrVersion, &ullVersion));
            // get the major version number
            ullVersion >>= 48L;
            if (ullVersion == version)
            {
                ISetupInstance2Ptr instance2(instance);
                LPSAFEARRAY psa = NULL;
                checkResult(instance2->GetPackages(&psa));
                safearray_ptr psa_ptr(&psa);
                // Lock the SAFEARRAY to get the raw pointer array.
                checkResult(::SafeArrayLock(psa));

                auto rgpPackages = reinterpret_cast<ISetupPackageReference**>(psa->pvData);
                auto cPackages = psa->rgsabound[0].cElements;

                if (0 != cPackages)
                {
                    vector< ISetupPackageReference* > packages(rgpPackages, rgpPackages + cPackages);
                    for (auto pPackage : packages)
                    {
                        bstr_t bstrType;
                        checkResult(pPackage->GetType(bstrType.GetAddress()));
                        bstr_t bstrID;
                        checkResult(pPackage->GetId(bstrID.GetAddress()));
                        if (VCCompilerType == wstring(bstrType) && VCCompilerID == wstring(bstrID))
                        {
                            bstr_t bstrInstallationPath;
                            instance2->GetInstallationPath(bstrInstallationPath.GetAddress());


                            return ERROR_SUCCESS;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            hr = e->Next(1, pInstances, NULL);
        }

        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            throw win32_exception(hr, "failed to enumerate all instances");
        }
    }
    catch (win32_exception)
    {

        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    }
    catch (exception)
    {

        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    }


    return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
}

void checkResult(HRESULT hr)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        throw win32_exception(hr, "call failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: hopefully the above helps with more specific options

Comment: FWIW, I've been using this API since its beta days in a commercial product I sell and there's never been a reported issue of it failing by any customer, nor have I ever seen it fail myself after countless runs (for VS2017 when it was originally released, up to and including the latest release of VS, 2022 at this writing). Not saying there isn't an issue in your own experience assuming your code is accurate, just saying.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio edition is located below the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\<version>`.

The name of the subkey(s) below the above will define the installed
Visual Studio edition(s), as follows:

```
Visual Studio 6 - 6.0
Visual Studio .NET (2002) - 7.0
Visual Studio .NET 2003 - 7.1
Visual Studio 2005 - 8.0
Visual Studio 2008 - 9.0
Visual Studio 2010 - 10.0
Visual Studio 2012 - 11.0
Visual Studio 2013 - 12.0
Visual Studio 2015 - 14.0
Visual Studio 2017 - 15.0
Visual Studio 2019 - 16.0
```

In my experience these are the version numbers that you will find,
but it's always possible that some VS version has added a sub-version
number after the point.

I could verify that this key exists starting with Visual Studio 2008, but cannot
guarantee it for earlier versions.

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. I have 2019 installed, but I only have 15.0 under Servicing

Comment: @TatianaRacheva: That's also my case. In the VS2019 About page I still find version 16. Seems like Microsoft has forgotten to increment the registry for VS2019 (or left it as 15 for some compatibility reason).